# MySQL Insert changes value of password

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have an issue with some Insert statements. I have the following Query to insert an admin to the system:

```
INSERT INTO user_data (USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES('admin', '$2a$10$W9xQIwa/FstPUvcbzJXnQ.XjVdTyIcCEp.g6VCq1gYuSsQNjJjbJG');
```

The password is the crypted form of "passwd".
But if I want to SELECT the entry, i get the following password:

```
a0/FstPUvcbzJXnQ.XjVdTyIcCEp.g6VCq1gYuSsQNjJjbJG
```

At first I thought anywhere in the code the password got changed, but if i want to insert the following:

```
INSERT INTO user_data (USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES('admin', 'passwd');
```

The password is "passwd" in the database.

Any clues why I have the problem?

EDIT:

The definition of user_data is the following:

```
create table user_data (username varchar(255) not null, birthday varchar(255), email varchar(255) not null, first_name varchar(255) not null, img_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255) not null, location varchar(255) not null, notification bit default false not null, password varchar(255) not null, phone_number varchar(255), postcode varchar(255) not null, religion varchar(255), street_name varchar(255) not null, user_role varchar(255), primary key (username));
```

I tried to insert the data manually with the teminal, and this works fine. Only if I put the insert lines into the vagrant script, I got the weird output.

Comment: Where are you running this from? PHP?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the definition of your `user_data` table. Possible column size or character set issue.

Comment: I run this in a vagrant script. At first, I define the tables, then i insert some test data and then i start the spring application.

Comment: It sounds as though you might have data assigned to the variables that you are inserting. Assuming you are running this from inside a double-quoted PHP string, the insert will attempt to insert the variable values, rather than the actual `$` characters. Another possibility is column size being too small for the inserted data.

Comment: somewhere, `$2` and `$1` are being interpreted as variables that contain no value and are being replaced with nothing. looks suspiciously like regex behavior.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing me in the right direction. It seems that the shell script interpret the $ as variables. So I have to do a workaround, that the password is understand as a string.